# Como confirmar la linea del autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, html5

soy nuevo en la programación, me sucede que varias veces el autocomplete del vsc, acierta en lo que quiero rellenar en la linea, pero no se como aceptarla probé con todas las teclas y en internet tampoco me da ninguna respuesta, ni ningún atajo de teclado, seguro es algo sencillo pero que ya vengo arrastrando hace mucho tiempo.

Comment: Es con "Enter".

Comment: Es con lo primero que probé, pero no funciona, será que tengo que configurarlo ? creo que es el tabnine

Comment: Normalmente no, pero podría ser que el `plugin` que estés utilizando sea diferente. En diferentes IDE's la forma más común de "aceptar" la sugerencia es con "Enter" y con el tabulador.

Comment: Ya probé y si era con tab muchas gracias!!! :)

Comment: Nicolás, no olvides colocarlo como respuesta (en base a [answer]) y [aceptarla](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.